# Tourist Visa on arrival in Luxor in the late evening

Tags: tourist-visas, egypt

Is a tourist (a UK national) able to obtain their tourist visa on arrival in Luxor, even when their plane lands at about 22:30? Will the visa office be closed then, or anything awkward like that?

http://www.luxortraveltips.com/essentials/arriving.htm says:

> Visas are available from the many bank kiosks in the arrival hall. They are next to each other along the left wall as you enter the airport terminal building.
>
> They will only accept notes, not coins, so you have to offer the next highest amount using notes. As long as the £ is worth more than $1.25, offering a British £20 note (each person) will get you a visa and some change in egyptian currency.

... which implies that you get them from staff.

Comment: I’d expect at least one bank kiosk to remain open until the final flight of the day has arrived and all its passengers have completed the relevant immigration formalities

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few years ago I caught a similar late flight from the UK, the booths were open for us to use. Many official government websites advertise the visa on arrival process for Egypt, so it will realistically always be open until the last flight of the day, as otherwise money would be lost, and people wouldn't be able to pass through immigration.

There are also always travel agents selling visas on the opposite side of the room for an inflated price, so if the booths ever were shut for some reason, they could be bought there instead.

And finally, the [official website](https://www.visa2egypt.gov.eg/eVisa/Home?VISTK=B2OW-6CU8-DELJ-7GRK-8Y4B-G0YP-ZZJZ-IYW7-THBQ-PNB8-RSL8-DL4N-HY08-55LL-6U5F-235R) also allow tourist visas to be purchased in advance if you want to be 1000% sure before you go!